# How can I trigger automatically print to pdf upon submission with NextJS and React-pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase, react-pdf

I have a submission form where I would like to call a function to automatically generate a PDF when submitted. However, the submission form is done in a server component. What I also would like to do here is to pass the `order_id` to the generating PDF:

```
// Create Document Component
  export function BasicDocument({order, total, user, order_id} : BasicDocumentProps) {
    return (
        <Document>
          {/*render a single page*/}
          <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
          <InvoiceTitle title='Your Order'/> //pass the order_id here
          <View>
            <Text>Cart Items: {JSON.stringify(order, null, 2)}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
          </Page>
        </Document>
    );
  }
  export default BasicDocument;
```

My form submission:

```
'use server'

import { createServerActionClient} from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"


export default async function addCustomerOrder(cart: any, total: number, formData: FormData): Promise<{ message: string }> {     
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createServerActionClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })

    try{
            //rest of the codes

              
                //this is the order_id that I would like to pass on the generating of the PDF.
                const order_id = orderData?.[0]?.order_id;
                
                //rest of the codes...
            return {  message: `Succesfully added the data` }
    }catch(e){
        return {message: "Failed to submit the form."}
    }

}
```

To generate a PDF: In generating this PDF, this kind of serves as a button from the `react-pdf`

```
 <PDFDownloadLink document={<BasicDocument cart={cart} total={total} user={user}/>} fileName="my-order.pdf">
        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
          loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!'
        }
      </PDFDownloadLink>
```

Comment: I did not understand the question clearly, is it like you are not getting `order_id` on client side or something? If you are getting it on client side, then you can pass order details in props of `<PDFDownloadLink document={<BasicDocument **order={...order}** cart={cart} total={total} user={user}/>} fileName="my-order.pdf">`